# Flask - How to talk to a spring microservices running on 8080

Tags: flask

I have a spring boot application running under my local node 8080 which gives me a list of users on http://localhost:8080/users

How can I get those users inside my Flask running on 5000?

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, current_app
import requests
@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def cust_search():
    r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/users')
    #users = request.form.get('userList')
    users = request.get_json()
    print(users)
    return jsonify(users), 200
```

The above code is not getting the users list json. Couldn't find info googling. I am new to Flask.

Any help please.

Comment: what is being returned?   also, try ```users = r.json()```  then you won't need to ```return jsonify(users)```.  you'd just need to ```return users, 200```  kinda along the lines of : https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

Answer (score 1):

Solution was as follows:

```
def cust_search():
    r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/users')
    users = r.json()
    return users, 200
```

Comment: You might want to pass a `timeout` argument to `requests.get` if [doing that in production](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts).